# How to set a GPIO pin HIGH in a STM32 MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded

Just recently pick-up a [ST-NUCLEO-32](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-l432kc.html) to upgrade from an Atmel Atmega328p.

The board integrates the [STM32L432KC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l432kc.pdf)

I am just playing around with the new MCU and having a harder than usual time setting Pin "PA_07" High.

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
    /* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32l432xx.h"

int main(void)
{
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= 0x01;
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x4000;
    GPIOA->OTYPER &= ~0x80;
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR &= ~0xC000;
    GPIOA->PUPDR  &= ~0xC000;
    GPIOA->BSRR |= 0x80;

  while (1)
  {

  }

}
```

Comment: if you look at the documentation port a MODER reset 0xABFFFFFF so you simply set a bit that is already set and left it in analog mode.  instead x = GPIOA->MODER; x&=~0xc000; x|=0x4000; GPIOA->MODER=x;  no need to mess with speed and pupdir to get a push/pull output.

Comment: Oh, is that the default value essentially when the MCU resets?

Comment: I tried setting the operator to "=" instead still not working?

Comment: User LD3: the green LED is a user LED connected to Arduino Nano signal D13
corresponding to the STM32 I/O PB3

Comment: is this the led you are trying to turn on?   pa7 looks to be just an analog input A6

Comment: try PB3 instead of PA7, and be very careful just jamming settings by writing with an = rather than read-modify-write even clearing those two bits then setting them with two writes to the register has risks check the schematic and datasheet first.   I have bricked some number of boards before I learned not to just force a whole register to change one pin.

Comment: yes that is the default please read the documentation, before you write your first line of code at this level you read the docs.  in the case of ST the datasheet for the target part, the reference manual for the target part, and similar docs for the nucleo board including where the led is and whether driving high or low will turn on the user led.